# Error in string index out of range: maf file to fasta file

Tags: python

Context: I am trying to convert a maf file (multiple alignment file) to individual fasta file. I keep running into the same error that I'm not sure how to fix and this may be because I'm relatively new to python. My code is below:

```
open_file = open('C:/Users/Danielle/Desktop/Maf_file.maf','r')
for record in open_file:
    print(record[2:7])
    if (record[2] == 'Z'):
        new_file = open(record[2:7]+".fasta",'w')
        header = ">"+record[2:7]+"\n"  
        sequence = record[46:len(record)] 
        new_file.write(header)
        new_file.write(sequence)
        new_file.close()
    else:
        print("Not correct isolate.")
open_file.close()
```

The error I get is:

```
IndexError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
      2 for record in open_file:
      3     print(record[2:7])
----> 4     if (record[2] == 'Z'):
      5         new_file = open(record[2:7]+".fasta",'w')
      6         header = ">"+record[2:7]+"\n"
IndexError: string index out of range
```

If I remove the if, else statement it works as I expect but I would like to filter for specific species that start with the character Z.

If anyone could help explain why I can't select for only strings that start with the character Z this way, that would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `record` formatted ? It seems that some record have length <= 2, possibly blank ?

Comment: more generally, the `IndexError: string index out of range` error will occur if `record` is shorter than 3 items, and Python cannot access item `[2]`

Comment: does it ever fail on the `print`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its giving an error when the length of record is less than 2.

To fix this you can change your if statement to:

```
if (len(record) > 2 and record[2] == 'Z'):
```

Ideally you should also handle such cases before separately.

Comment: might also want to do the same for the `print` statement since that is indexing into `record` as well.

Comment: sure, but it won't throw an error, it will just print a blank line

Comment: @pyjg it's not necessary for the print as it's slicing try this: `""[10:20]`. Slice will slice as much as it can but will return empty things if the slice is out of range.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes sense why it didn't work before. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative answer.

The problem you're having is because the record you're reading might not have at least 3 chars. For that reason you have to check the length of the string before checking index 2. As you might have noticed, the line 3 doesn't crash.

Slice operator in short will slice from index 2 to 7 returning anything it finds.

So if you have let look at this:

```
"abcd"[1:] == "bcd"
"abcd"[1:3] == "bc"
"abcd"[1:10] == "bcd"
"abcd"[4:] == ""
```

As you can see, it will return anything from index 1 to index 2 excluded. When it doesn't find anything the slice operation stop and return.

So one different way to get the same result as checking for the length would be to do this:

```
if (record[2:3] == 'Z'):
```

This way, you're slicing the char at index 2, if the index exists it will return a char otherwise an empty string. That said, I can't say if the slice operation will be faster than checking the length of the string and getting the index then. In some ways, the slice operation does that internally most probably.

Answer (score 0):

A better answer

This way, we can fix the problem you had and also make it a bit more efficient. You're slicing multiple time the record for `[2:7]` you should store that in a variable. If the index 2 isn't present in the resulting filename, we can assume the filename is empty. If the filename is empty it will be falsy, if not we can check index 0 because it's certainly will be there and index 0 of filename is index 2 of record.

Second problem is to use the format string instead of `+` operator. It will convert anything you pass to the format string to a string as the format passed is `%s`. If you'd pass a False or None value, the program will crash as arithmetic operation are only allowed for `str + str`.

```
open_file = open('C:/Users/Danielle/Desktop/Maf_file.maf','r')

for record in open_file:
    filename = record[2:7]
    print(filename)

    if (filename and filename[0] == 'Z'):
        with open("%s.fasta" % filename,'w') as newfile:
            header = ">%s\n" % filename
            sequence = record[46:len(record)] 
            new_file.write(header)
            new_file.write(sequence)
    else:
        print("Not correct isolate.")

open_file.close()
```

A bit of reformat and we'd end up with this:

```
def write_fasta(record):
    filename = record[2:7]
    print(filename)

    if (filename and filename[0] == 'Z'):
        with open("%s.fasta" % filename,'w') as new_file:
            header = ">%s\n" % filename
            sequence = record[46:len(record)] 
            new_file.write(header)
            new_file.write(sequence)
    else:
        print("Not correct isolate.")

maf_filename = 'C:/Users/Danielle/Desktop/Maf_file.maf'
with open(maf_filename, 'r') as maf:
    for record in maf:
        write_fasta(record)
```

Use the context manager whenever possible as they'll handle the file closing themselves. So no need to explicitly call the `close()` method.